# nm-applet doesn't use appindicator

Tags: debian, notification-area, networkmanager, enlightenment

I've been trying enlightenment as DE in Debian Jessie. Unfortunately, they dropped the xembed support in E20, so only libappindicator-aware applications show up on the systray.

Theoretically, nm-applet supports appindicator since 0.8.3, but it doesn't show up in the systray. blueman for example does show in the systray

libappindicator1 and libappindicator3-1 are installed.

My initial hypotheses were:

1. e20 is SOMEHOW reporting it provides an xembed-capable systray and some applications use it by default, falling back on libappindicator when not available
2. nm-applet still does not work using libappindicator.
3. I messed up something different entirely

I tried to run nm-applet in Debian Stretch in e20 and Plasma 5, which is another DE that does no longer support xembed.

It still failed in both e20 and plasma 5, which rules out #1

Either I'm not doing something correctly or nm-applet (or at least the Debian version) does not support libappindicator?

I've currently ran out of ideas :(

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same setup in Arch linux. Enlightenment 0.21 and NM. To make it work, you need to build NetworkManager from git, since the appindicator support has not been released yet, but it's in the master branch. You need to compile with --with-appindicator flag, and then run nm-apple --indicator.

You could also try running nm-applet with the --indicator flag in Debian, perhaps it's already in the binary, before compiling from source.

Here's  the bug:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740574

Comment: I will try today when I get home

Thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: I've been trying to compile network-manager 1.2 in debian, but debian's dependencies are too old and I'll have to compile too many packages, so I opted out for the time being.

Nonetheless, I did see that from version 1.2 onwards, there's the --with-appindicator switch, which pretty much settles it. I'm selecting your answer as correct, thank you so much!

Comment: I just saw that the ubuntu guys did patch the old releases with appindicator.

I'll try my luck compiling that